# Contextual help in wp-admin for non admins

Tags: wp-admin, contextual-help

I'm having a problem. I have my WP with custom roles, capabilities and so on.. But I'm having a problem in displaying the context help (in top right corner). If I log in as admin-it's all right - it's there, if I login with account which doesn't have admin rights -it's not there. But I want to display help for lower level accounts too, how to do that? I think this is a WP core thing..can it be overwritten without changing the core?

***my code of displaying it***:

```
  add_action( 'load-post.php', 'wpd_help_post' );
  function wpd_help_post() {
  $screen = get_current_screen();
//my custom post types
    if ( $screen->id == 'albumas' || $screen->id == 'edit-albumas' ) {
      $screen->add_help_tab( array(
          'id'      => 'wpd-base',
          'title'   => __('My title', 'sfc'),
          'content' => '<h3>My help text</h3>',
      ));
    }
  }
```

Well I was stupid this time, everything is working, no matter which user. I forgot to add an action for creating a new entry and only added it for editing. That's why I was unable to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contextual help code doesn't make any discrimination on user-level by default. If you can see the page, the contextual help is there too.

Are you using some custom code, and hiding the help stuff behind a level check, by chance? More information than what you have provided is needed.

Comment: thanks for quick replay, but i search whole code and there is nothing what can hide them... :( i wrote the whole thing and i don't remember that i was hiding them..

Comment: It may not be obvious. Like, if you have the add_help_tab function call inside a function that is only called for specific users or something... Things like that. Edit: Looked at your code. Why are you hooking to "load-post.php"? Try "admin-init" instead.

Comment: WP codex says use load-BLABLABLA for help tabs, so i'm using it, and change to admin-init doesn't change anything -tried. Also my function is called for all users it's in functions.php file without any condition. Also i unhidded menu items-did not help, still nothing. I also looked at sourse to see maybe i used JavaScript to hide it-nope..there is no code to do that.Maybe WP shows it for regular roles not custom ones...

Comment: Okay, I guess I was confused about what you were trying to do. I tried your code on a test site, and it works fine as long as the $screen->id is set to "albumas". Are you sure that bit is correct? What happens when you var_dump the $screen->id? Are you sure you have the right ID value there? Can you post what your custom post type code looks like?

Comment: well maybe you're right after all. i just noticed that this doesn't work if even admin is logged in. It displays help tab if i edit my entry but if i create new-there is no help tab in creating new entry. now i'm searching how to add it to create window in my post type.